# how to find out if a AWS.EC2.runInstances created succefully an instance or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, promise

I'm facing a trouble right now, I don't know if I am still confused with the PROMISE concept, but I'm using the API from AWS SDK to create instance via javascript (nodejs). The issue I'm having right now is: I want to increment an acum for both cases (Successfullly Created or Fail Created) that may occurs when I'm runing this app. I'm using the Amazon Documentation Example.

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Load credentials and set region from JSON file
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');

// Create EC2 service object
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});

// AMI is amzn-ami-2011.09.1.x86_64-ebs
var instanceParams = {
   ImageId: 'ami-10fd7020', 
   InstanceType: 't1.micro',
   KeyName: 'KEY_PAIR_NAME',
   MinCount: 1,
   MaxCount: 1
};

// Create a promise on an EC2 service object
var instancePromise = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'}).runInstances(instanceParams).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
instancePromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var instanceId = data.Instances[0].InstanceId;
    return {success: 1};        
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
    return {failed: 1};
  });
```

I suppose to consume this server in my client side and I'm incremening my acum in my client depending of this service response, if fail then failAcum++ or success then successAcum++, etc.

the point is than everyone instance is counting as FAILED, because the service is returning fail in ever call, instead, the instances are being created anyways.

what I understand about promises is: 'if promise resolve OK it goes into "then" if any issue, error, problem occurs then it goes to "catch". so How is possible the instances are being created and it's going directly to CATCH.

Please I really need your help, I've been in this point since 3 days ago, I really need to solve it. if there is other way to do it, I'm open to follow your tips and suggestions...

Thank you so much before hand, I wish you a Great Day.

Comment: If your console.error() line of code is executing, what is it actually logging?

Comment: Yes, the console.error() is being trigged, for differents reasons, ej:
No available instance to create,

Comment: Well, I would record the exact error messages ("No available instance to create" doesn't seem correct) and investigate them. Also, how is this code actually called and how is it supposed to return values to the caller? Right now it just seems to be inline JavaScript that you execute standalone.

Comment: This is an API than I call N times within a foearch in my client side. The exact error I'm not sure if it matters, because in fact there's no just one error. I don't need to handle errors, i just want to know how many instances were created and how many weren't created.